# Scala, Spray - Unmarshalling to List[Int]

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json, akka-http

I'm trying to get list of ints `[1,2,3,...]` from JSON api but I see conversion to generic type isn't working and Spray documentation is only showing unmarshalling to specific object. Any ideas how to make it work / what to google to get my answer?

API endpoint: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json

```
import java.io.IOException

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpResponse, HttpRequest}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding
import scala.concurrent.Future

object NewsDaemon extends App{
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  case class HNResultList(items: List[Int])

  val hnConnectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] =
    Http().outgoingConnectionTls(config.getString("services.hnApiHost"))

  def hnApiRequest (request: HttpRequest) : Future[HttpResponse] = Source.single(request).via(hnConnectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)

    hnApiRequest(RequestBuilding.Get("/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty")).flatMap { response =>
      response.status match {
        case OK => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[List[Int]].map(println)
        case _ => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { entity =>
          val error = s"HN API request failed with status code ${response.status} and entity $entity"
          Future.failed(new IOException(error))
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport`:

```
object NewsDaemon extends App with SprayJsonSupport {
...
}
```

spray-json library supports basic types and collections 'out-of-box'.

You can find implementation here:

- basic types: `spray.json.BasicFormats`
- collections: `spray.json.CollectionFormats`

So you do not have to write your own JsonFormat (JsonReader/JsonWriter) for this types.

Detailed explaination how to integrate spray-json with akka-http you can find here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/http/common/json-support.html